# Flutter App crashes when Launching after I close it using Device back button

Tags: flutter, dart

Sorry!! The question may be duplicate but I'm unable to found the solution. Here is my problem
I Completed my flutter app and Almost Everything works fine but there is one problem. I close The app using the Device Back Button and when I open it again first White Screen opens and after some second Black Screen opens and stay on That black Screen (stuck on black Screen) app Crashes

Here is Everything you need.

My Folder Structure is, user SIGNUP() or login(), I have a login and signup page(), from the login or signup page when the user presses the login or signup button he Goes to HomeControllerpage() page
HomeControllerPage() is a page that Authenticates the user and Redirects to homePage() if the user is Authenticated. otherwise, the user Redirects to the login/signup page again if he or she is not authenticated

```
Here is my Main.dart

void main()async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp().catchError((e) {
    print(e);

  });
  runApp(
      Myapp());
  
}
class Myapp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Myapp> createState() => _MyappState();
}

class _MyappState extends State<Myapp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Provider(
          auth: Authservice(),
        child: MaterialApp(
       title: 'signup',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        ),
          initialRoute:  '/home',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        //flutter  home:email==null? homecontroller(controllUserType: 'hfdd',):null,
          routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
          '/home':(BuildContext context)=>homecontroller(),
         '/Signup':(BuildContext context)=>signup_view(authFormType: AuthFormType.Signup,),
          '/SignIn':(BuildContext context)=>signup_view(authFormType: AuthFormType.SignIn,),
         '/dropDown':(BuildContext context)=>dropDown()//delet this
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

}

```
 Here is how the user Signup, Signup() page

     Future<String> CreateUserUisngEmailAndPassword(
          BuildContext context,
        String _firstname,
        String _userID,
        String _dropDownValue,
      ) async {
        try {
          final UserCredential Newuser = await _firebaseAuth
              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: _password);
          User curentRegistereduser = Newuser.user;
          await AddToDataBase(uid: curentRegistereduser.uid).firebaseuserdata(
              _firstname,
              _userID=curentRegistereduser.uid,
          );
    
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>homecontroller(
                controllUserType:_dropDownValue,
                userid:_userID,
              )));
        }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
            print('The password provided is too weak.');
          } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
            print('The account already exists for that email.');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
        //Update User
      }
```

---

```
Here is How user Login. / Loginpage()

   Future loginWithEmailAndPasswords(String email, String password,BuildContext context) async {
        try {
    
          UserCredential register = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email, password: password);
          User registredUser = register.user;
          final ownerSnapshots= await ownerReference.doc(registredUser.uid).get();
          final userSnapshots= await  userSnapshot.doc(registredUser.uid).get();
    
          if(ownerSnapshots.exists){
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>homecontroller(
        controllUserType:ownerSnapshots.data()['Account type'].toString(),
        userid: ownerSnapshots.data()['userId'].toString(),
    
      )));
         }else if(userSnapshots.exists){
    
           Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>homecontroller(
                   controllUserType:userSnapshots.data()['Account type'].toString(),
                   userid: userSnapshots.data()['userId'].toString(),
    
                 )));
    
           } else{
             return null;
           }
        }
        on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
        } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
        }
        }
      }
```

---

```
Here is My HomeController Page.

    class homecontroller extends StatelessWidget {
      final String controllUserType;
      final String userid;
       const homecontroller({Key key,@required this.controllUserType,@required this.userid}):super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Authservice auth
        final Authservice auth=Provider.of(context).auth;
        return StreamBuilder(
              stream:auth.authStateChanges,
              builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<String>snapshot){
              if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active){
                final bool SignedIn=snapshot.hasData;
                return SignedIn?HomePage(UserType:controllUserType,userID: userid,):firstview();
              }else{
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              },
        );
      }
    }
```

---

```
 finally Here is My home page()
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      final String UserType;
      final String userID;
    
      const HomePage({Key key,@required this.UserType,@required this.userID}):super(key: key);
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      DateTime backButtunPressedtime;
      bool isSignedIn= false;
      int _CurrentIndex=0;
      String owneruerID;
      dynamic uploadusertypes;
      List<Widget>_children;
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        uploadusertypes= widget.UserType;
        owneruerID = widget.userID;
        _children=[
          TimeLinePage(),
          SearchPage(), //search(),
          UploadPage(UserSID:owneruerID,uploadusertypes:uploadusertypes),
          NotificationsPage(),
          ProfilePage(userProfileID:widget.userID),
        ];
       
        if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null){
            setState(() {
              isSignedIn= true;
            });
          }else{
            setState(() {
              isSignedIn= false;
               });
          }
    
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if(isSignedIn){
     if(widget.UserType== 'Customer'){
     return Scaffold(
       body: WillPopScope(
         onWillPop: onwillpops,
         child: buildHomeScreen(),
       ),
     );
         }
      else{
   return Scaffold(
       body: WillPopScope(
         onWillPop: onwillpops,
         child:buildSignedInScreen(),
       ),
    
      }return Container(
        height: 0.0,
        width: 0.0,
      );
      }
    Scaffold buildSignedInScreen(){
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
          body: _agentchildren[_agentCurrentIndex],
    
          bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            currentIndex: _agentCurrentIndex,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            onTap: agentonTabchangePage,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveColor: Colors.white10,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.home),title: Text('home'),),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.search)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.notifications)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1_sharp)),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
        Scaffold buildHomeScreen(){
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              body: _children[_CurrentIndex],
              bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
                currentIndex: _CurrentIndex,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                onTap: onTabchangePage,
                activeColor: Colors.green,
                inactiveColor: Colors.white,
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.home),title: Text('home'),),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.search)),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.photo_camera,size: 40,)),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.notifications)),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1_sharp)),
                ],
              ),
            );
        }
    
      void onTabchangePage(int index) {
        setState(() {
          _CurrentIndex=  index;
        });
    
      }
    
      Future<bool> onwillpops()async {
        DateTime curentTime= DateTime.now();
        //if backbutton is not pressed or toast mesge closed
        bool bckbutton= backButtunPressedtime==null||curentTime.difference(backButtunPressedtime)>Duration(seconds: 3);
        if(bckbutton){
          backButtunPressedtime= curentTime;
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Double Click to exit app",
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            textColor: Colors.white,
          );
          return false;
        }
       return true;
      }
    
    }
```

Here is The problem that happened to me. In my home page I use WillPopScope to Handle The device Back button, and when I close the app by using The device Back Button The app exits or closes as Expected but when Reopen again, the first white Screen page displayed and after 3 or 4 seconds The Second Black Screen page Displayed, and Stay at That Black Screen page or app Crashes

Comment: where is your starting page, the child of MaterialApp?

Comment: I ADD MY ( Main. dart ) file in my post, please read it again I post it now on the above my  Questions.

Comment: please add stacktrace of crash

Answer (score 0):

If you are using named routes and your route names start with `/`, then the initial route must be `"/"` only. Otherwise, don't use `/` in route names.

Also, don't hardcode named routes, you may misspell it. Instead, save it in a constants file.

Comment: so How I can Correct it in my code? is it the Error That makes my APP crash?

Comment: try removing `/` from all route names,  for starters. eg. `/home` to `home`

Comment: you are not even using named routes!

Comment: just remove all `/` for now, then report. Its something like web URL where / refers to home page, /anotherpage to another page etc.

Comment: The problem Still Exist Even if i changed "/home " to home,

Comment: do you have stack trace of crash?

Comment: I did not use any of this named route on my page, only where  I use this named route is at Initial route problem Still Exist Even if I changed "/home " to home,